# What does 토끼고싶다 mean?

Tags: internet-slang

I understand that it's a pun incorporating 토끼, but I'm having trouble figuring out what it means. I've seen it used in Kakao and Instagram.

Comment: seen it where? example sentence?

Comment: that's pretty old slang. '야! 토껴!!' means 'Hey! run away!!'

Comment: another slang with simillar meaning is '튀다'. e.g '경찰이다 튀어!' 'it's police! run!'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 토끼고싶다 - *I want to ditch this scene.*

It has a negative connotation. A nicer way to say the same thing might be:

> 도망가고싶다 - *I want to escape/run away.*

It's also heard used like this as a collective (we):

> 토끼자 - *Let's ditch this place.*

And this way in the past (1st person or collective) tense:

> 토꼈어 - *i/we ditched that place.*

Again, it's kind of not nice.

Answer (score 0):

It may sounds like a slang and the certainly the usage may be so.
However, it is a word that is listed in the [Korean dictionary](http://krdic.naver.com/seo.nhn?id=39493000).

I used "토꼈어" mostly in the situation where any authority might have a say on the issue.